# Ctrl f11 "view animation" shows 2 separate animations from 2 separate projects

Tags: animation

When I press ctrl f11 to view animation it shows an animation from a different project then once that animation is finished shows the second half of the animation from the current project I'm trying to view. Also both project's animations have low fps when viewing the rendered animation (ctrl f12).

Comment: What do your render settings look like? Is the animation rendered as separate images? Maybe you rendered it into the same folder? Without more information, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: How do you check the render settings?

Comment: It's in the *Output Properties* tab ("printer" icon): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnAog.png Have you checked if the output folder is empty?

Comment: Mine shows the exact same thing as the picture you sent.